# How to get images dynamic loaded with scrapy-playwright?

Tags: extract, scrapy-playwright

I am working on a web scraping bot that gets specific images dynamically loaded on the website.
For this project, I choose to work with scrapy and scrapy-playwright to load the pages.

Below is the website:
https://edition.pagesuite.com/html5/reader/production/default.aspx?pubname=&edid=e5d8807a-ac5e-4033-bf64-22eb37832e8d

For the moment I see the first image, I identify that all the images at a good scale are under the "printContainer" class.
There is another option with the "readerPage" class where the images are at a lower scale.

To load the rest of the images I need to turn the pages, and I don't know how to do that with scrapy-playwright.

What I want to do is to get all the images and save them in a folder.
I am grateful if you can help me with a hint or a solution to this problem.

Below is my source code.

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine

class BusinessAtlasSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = 'business_atlas' 
    allowed_domains = ['edition.pagesuite.com'] 
    start_urls = 'https://edition.pagesuite.com/'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://edition.pagesuite.com/html5/reader/production/default.aspx?pubname=&edid=e5d8807a-ac5e-4033-bf64-22eb37832e8d',
                             callback = self.parse, 
                             meta= dict(
                                        playwright = True,
                                        playwright_include_page =  True,
                                        playwright_page_coroutines = [
                                            # waiting for the selector to load the page
                                            PageCoroutine('wait_for_selector','div.x-inner.x-layout-card'),
                                            # trying to click to the next page
                                            PageCoroutine("evaluate",'document.querySelectorAll("div#ext-element-840").forEach(x=>x.click())'),                
                                            ]
                                        ))
        
    async def parse(self, response):
        # "printContainer" class, looks like it has the larger images
        image_selector = response.xpath('//*[@class="printContainer"]')
        # loop through the container for the images
        for image in image_selector:
            yield {
                    'link1': image.xpath('.//@src').extract_first(),
                    'link2': image.xpath('.//div[1]/img/@src').extract_first(),
                    'link3': image.xpath('.//div[2]/img/@src').extract_first(),
                
            }
```